# Можно ли запустить Yandex tank на macOS?

Tags: macos, яндекс-танк

Возможно ли запустить Yandex tank на macOS?

Comment: [RTFM, вот он](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)...

Answer (score 1):

На MacOS можно установить и запустить yandex-tank. По мануалу использовать метод установки через PyPi - но у вас **по умолчанию в ОС должен стоять python 2.7**